# The pronunciation of the name "Hinds"

Tags: pronunciation

As far as I know, the pronunciation of the name "Hinds" is /haindz/. Is there another way to pronounce this word? Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with names is that they're ultimately pronounced the way the owner wants them to be pronounced. You can try to apply rules, but there'll always be an exception somewhere.

That said, the word *could* be pronounced /hɪndz/ - consider *wind* and *winds*, both as the blowy thing in the air and the way to put cotton onto a reel - so *Hinds* could follow the same pattern.

It's most likely to be /hʌɪndz/, however, as it's most likely (that qualifier again) to be derived from *[hind](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hind)* (definition 2):

> A female deer

or *perhaps* definition 3:

> A skilled farm worker

Comment: You are right. A friend of mine told me that this name is pronounced like /Hindz/. Looking it up in a lot of dictionaries, I did'nt get any information.